# How to correct checkbox position, when it is one the same page with jQuery UI input text?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I've placed several text inputs on the page styled with:

> ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget-content ui-corner-all

Now I need to add one checkbox to the same page. But somehow it is centered. How can I make it left aligned?

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget"><label for="link">Link: </label><input type="text" id="link" name="link" placeholder="" class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>
<div class="ui-widget"><input type="checkbox" id="cb-anonymous">Anonymous</div>
```

CSS:

```
label {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
input {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/sY9Fa/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the checkbox isen't centerd it has just a width of 200px because you set the width of all input elements to 200px.

so thats why you should specify your input which you wana be 200px width: `input[type="text"]`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sY9Fa/1/

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I've chosen wrong example, since I also have combobox jQuery UI elements on the page and `input` style worked for them as well. When I changed that to `input[type="text"]` their buttons moved to the next line.

Comment: OK, `#cb-anonymous  { width: auto; }` helped.